# Samba server doesn't notice changed password

Tags: 14.04, server, samba

I've tied samba to unix passwords via

```
security = user
```

and

```
unix password sync = yes
```

Previously this has worked very well. I recently upgraded my server to 14.04 (server) though. I changed my linux user password the first time since the upgrade now, with the result that samba won't recognize the changed password - it still expects the user's old one.

I have restarted the `smbd` service, but no change. What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue after upgrading from Debian Squeeze to Wheezy. Other posts I saw suggested installing the [libpam-smbpass](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libpam-smbpass) package.

After I installed libpam-smbpass, changes to a user's system password were immediately reflected by Samba. (If the share was previously connected on a Windows machine, I did find that I had to log off and log back on to that Windows machine in order to use the new password.)

Comment: @AibaraIduas It looks like an answer to me..

Comment: Yes this works very well! Any idea why that isn't installed by default?

Comment: Hm seems this library is causing other problems: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1257186
possibly I uninstalled it because of this ;)